# Changing one build option in a package

Tags: packaging

I want to use the graphviz package on an Ubuntu system, but according to the build log it is configured using `--without-gts`, whereas I want GTS support to be included (I don't know if there's a reason why it isn't, or if it's just an arbitrary decision).

What's the best way to go about doing this? Ideally I want to keep my build as close as possible to the one shipped in Ubuntu, as that would make it easier to get the change merged in at a later date. I'm struggling to find any guides which show how to do this - they all seem to assume you want to package new software from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general procedure for changing build options for an Ubuntu/Debian package goes like this:

1. Get the build dependencies
2. Download the source package
3. Change the appropriate files (usually `debian/rules`)
4. Build the packages
5. Install the packages

The commands involved:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep graphviz
apt-get source graphviz
cd graphviz-* # Or check the directory with ls and pick the correct version
```

Then you can delete the configuration option from `debian/rules`, either using an editor, or:

```
sed -i '/--without-gts/d' debian/rules
```

<sup><sub>This command is specific to this instance, as there is only one match for `--without-gts` in `debian/rules`.</sub></sup>

Then build the package:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

This will create a bunch of packages in the parent directory. The options indicate the you don't wish to make a package for uploading to the Ubuntu repositories (and so don't want to sign them, etc.). Now you can install these packages:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb # or pick out the packages manually
```

The build dependencies may be different from the installation dependencies, so to install all the dependencies you might need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks, that's incredibly helpful. Sadly the package won't build even without changing the GTS option but that's something I'll have to look into.

Comment: There were a couple of errors about changed documentation PDF files when I tried, but otherwise it built successfully. What error did you get?

Comment: @pwaring I had made a typo: it should be `build-dep` instead of `build-deps`, sorry about that.

Comment: The final errors are:

```# Move from debian/tmp to the appropriate packages, rename one binary

dh_install --sourcedir=debian/tmp --list-missing

dh_install: libgvc6 missing files (usr/lib/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.*), aborting
make: *** [install] Error 255
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Comment: @pwaring Yeah, that's completely different from what I got, so I can't help much.