# software istallation

Tags: software-installation, libxml

I am trying to install the libxml2 library.during installing this error occures.

```
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/madhuv/y/libxml2-2.9.2/python'
CC libxml.lo
libxml.c:14:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include <Python.h>
^
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [libxml.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/madhuv/y/libxml2-2.9.2/python'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/madhuv/y/libxml2-2.9.2/python'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/madhuv/y/libxml2-2.9.2/python'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/madhuv/y/libxml2-2.9.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2.
```

please help me.

Comment: try installting `python-dev` by: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle a "No such file or directory" error for a header file from make?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592863/how-do-i-handle-a-no-such-file-or-directory-error-for-a-header-file-from-make)

Answer (score 1):

You need the development library `libpython-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython-dev
```

Currently the command installs `libpython2.7-dev`

---

```
$ apt-file search /Python.h

[..]
libpython2.7-dbg: /usr/include/python2.7_d/Python.h
libpython2.7-dev: /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
libpython3.4-dbg: /usr/include/python3.4dm/Python.h
libpython3.4-dev: /usr/include/python3.4m/Python.h
[..]
```